# Is it better to use graphs or tables to represent a confidence interval? Does it matter?

Tags: confidence-interval, data-visualization

I have a Poisson distribution CI (used Garwood, so it's not symmetrical), and I'm not sure whether it's better to present a CI in my research paper as a graph, table, or both.  If I should use a graph, what's the best software to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that confidence intervals are best represented by a thin line (no perpendicular tick marks needed), and an advantage of graphical presentation is that you can show more than one confidence level (e.g., 0.9, 0.95, 0.99) by using different line thicknesses or saturations.  As we move more to reports in html5, things will change.  For example with R plotly it is easy to make a plot as described above and to see the numerical values of the confidence limits by hovering the mouse over the area of interest.

Comment: [I agree with this](http://stats.blogoverflow.com/2012/02/some-notes-on-making-effective-tables/), but playing devil's advocate, if you report the linear coefficient and standard error in the table, those viewing the report can construct *their own* confidence intervals at whatever level they want. It is also useful for meta-analysis. (So I would say you should report both.)

Comment: Don't think so.  Many effects require multiple betas (e.g., quadratic, spline, categorical X).